# Set height of DIV in CSS based on top() and bottom()

Tags: css, html

The page I'm working on is at [www.joelchristophel.com](http://www.joelchristophel.com). You can see the source code by inspecting the elements in most browsers. I want the content div, called main_body, to fill in the area between the header and the main_bottom div. To do this, I've set the position of pixels from the top as well as pixels from the bottom. However, that isn't working because main_body is only expanding to the size of the content. How should I go about this?

EDIT: In the end, main_body should be fixed in place with overflow set to scroll.

Comment: do you want really to fix the footer to bottom? Keep in mind, that than maybe the content needs an ugly scrollbar. I would try to give main_body a min/max height

Comment: That's why overflow is set to scroll. Also, I'm not using a footer despite doing stuff with one in the CSS file.

Comment: so in your case a better approach would be to set page height to 100% and style the other heights relativ to page instead of using position fixed.

Comment: Could you maybe give as example as to how I'd achieve this via an answer as I'm extremely new to CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a percentage as the height. And removing the `bottom: 20;` line from `main_bottom`. That worked like a charm.

Comment: Your `bottom: 20;` is invalid. You don't have a doctype so you are in quirks. You got it to show what you want but you will be in a constant battle from here on out.

Comment: Can you expound a bit, as I'm completely new. (e.g. how to add a doctype, why I need one, etc.)

Comment: CSS requires 'units', such as px or em. What you have is like telling someone, "I live 20 away from here". A "document type" (doctype)  sets the standards mode for your document. Without one, it's like 1999 all over again. Standards mode is set by putting this on your very first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Much more here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you manually set the height of each div then play around with it. In your css for #main .main_body set:

```
height = 500px;
```

With 500 being any value you want. Then put your main_bottom div inside your main body div.

You should also have a look at this link: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks if you want to make a child div the same height as a parent div which may help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your requirement.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="content">
    Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!Content Comes Here..!!
</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
}

.content
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:10px;
    height:auto:
}

.footer
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Try It..!!